# Can I figure out which instance is currently used by an Elastic Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I have created two Amazon EC2 instances. After that I created an Elastic Load Balancer and registered the two instances in it.
Now what I would like to know is, when we use the DNS name of the load balancer, which instance will the load balancer use?

Answer (score 4):

The idea of [Load balancing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29) is *to distribute workload across multiple computers or a computer cluster, network links, central processing units, disk drives, or other resources [...]*.

While there are many algorithms conceivable, the general goal is to *achieve optimal resource utilization, maximize throughput, minimize response time, and avoid overload*, which usually implies transparent distribution of the load between the load balanced resources. Therefore you usually won't know (and shouldn't need to know), which load balanced resource serves a particular request.

Accordingly, [Elastic Load Balancing (ELB)](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) *automatically distributes incoming application traffic across multiple Amazon EC2 instances*.

How this is done specifically is a fairly complicated topic, mostly due to the ELB routing documentation falling short of being non existent, so one needs to assemble some pieces to draw a conclusion - see my answer to the related question [Can Elastic Load Balancers correctly distribute traffic to different size instances](https://serverfault.com/a/386527/10305) for a detailed analysis including all the references I'm aware of.

For the question at hand I think it boils down to the somewhat vague AWS team response from 2009 to [ELB Strategy](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=129199#129199):

> **ELB loosely keeps track of how many requests (or connections in the
>   case of TCP) are outstanding at each instance.**  It does not monitor
>   resource usage (such as CPU or memory) at each instance.  ELB
>   currently will round-robin amongst those instances that it believes
>   has the fewest outstanding requests. *[emphasis mine]*

Answer (score 1):

stf ,
you cannot come to know, for which server load is distributing through EBS , EBS internally take care of request distribution .

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can figure out which server your request goes to!

On each server you are going to need something akin to a health_check.html file (can be named anything, someone suggested index.htm but that is a bad idea and is another discussion entirely) so the load balancer can call it and determine how long it took to get a response.

On server #1 put the following in the health_check.html file: `<HTML><BODY>1</BODY></HTML>`

On server #2 put this in the health_check.html file: `<HTML><BODY>2</BODY></HTML>`

Now when you navigate to www.YourDomain.com/health_check.html you will know exactly which server you are on.

Clear your cookies and re-navigate to the same URL to see which server you get next. Good luck cloud developer!